# What's the best way to show slider value on a jLabel while dragging?

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I'm writing a Tournament System and I put a slider in my form.

I'm using the mouse dragging event handler on the slider to get and show the slider value on the jLabel, but I see there is a lot of CPU use only because of that feature(about 10% while dragging).

I am also using mouse click event handler, because sometimes the user clicks instead of dragging,thus the dragging handler event  would be useless in those cases.

```
    JLabel lblPorcentajePremio = new JLabel("");
    panel.add(lblPorcentajePremio, "cell 4 7");

    JSlider slider = new JSlider();
    slider.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            lblPorcentajePremio.setText(String.valueOf(slider.getValue()));
        }
    });

slider.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
            lblPorcentajePremio.setText(String.valueOf(slider.getValue()));
        }
    });
```

[image: GUI running]

Is there any more efficient way to do this? Thanks

Comment: ChangeListener is the canonical way to do this.

Comment: Agree with Hovercraft, though I'm not sure you'll see an appreciable difference in CPU overhead.